# How to bind plain text to keys

Tags: autohotkey

I want to bind some text to keys to quickly fill some webform so when I press some key it pastes some predefined text. For example:
a = "cat"
s = "dog"
d = "flower"
etc.
So I make script like:

```
a::
Send, dog
return

s::
Send, cat
return

d::
Send, flower
return
```

The problem is when I press 'a' key instead of "dog" it would print "ogflower". I just need it to paste plain text, without further transforming it to hotkeys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want the `$`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar)</sup> modifier to your hotkeys.

```
$a::SendInput, dog
$s::SendInput, cat
$d::SendInput, flower
```

Misc improvements:
One line hotkeys can be made into one liners, and switched to [SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) due to it being the recommended faster and more reliable sendmode.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for filling out forms is to use **hotstrings** instead of hotkeys.

I use the following scheme:

- n for name
- e for email
- p for phone
- s for street
- a for complete address
- z for zip

```
:*:xxn::Kevin McCabe
:*:xxe::myemail@gmail.com
:*:xxp::123-456-7890
:*:xxs::123 Main Street
:*:xxa::123 Main Street{enter}Long Island NY 12345
:*:xxz::12345-0000
```

The idea is to prefix with some characters to form a string you wouldn't normally type. Then you wouldn't be limited to just filling out webforms. These definitions could be global so they work in any document, editor, email etc.

The `:*:` causes the string to expand upon typing the last character of the string.

Whereas this form

`::btw::by the way`

is only triggered after typing a non-word character after the w.

On the rare occasion you actually want to type xxs for example, it's easy enough just to type it, let it expand, press `^z`, space, backspace and then retype the s.

Or just change to zz, qq or ** instead.